# Fix ALL CAPS in MS Access data

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

An MS Access 2010 table has a table `SomeTable` with a field `SomeField` which contains records that are all in ALL CAPS.  **What specific SQL query can I use to update `SomeTable.SomeField` so that each word in each row has a capital first letter and the rest lower case letters?**

For example, if the data in one row of `SomeTable.SomeField` is "FULL NAME", how do I structure the query that will turn it into "Full Name"?  And another row might be "ANOTHER NAME", which needs to turn into "Another Name", and so on.  And so on, with different names but the same formatting issue in every row of the table.

Comment: `UPDATE SomeTable set SomeField= StrConv(SomeField, 3)` should work.  Is it giving you an error?

Answer (score 4):

You need the StrConv function.  The syntax is `StrConv(string, conversion type)`.  The conversion type for proper case is 3.  See here for more info: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/converting-text-to-proper-case-in-access/

Comment: BTW, Jim actually wrote the specific code necessary (you'll have to change the table and field names, obviously) in the comment below the question.  If that code works, please consider upvoting this answer.